# Relative schematic density: reducing to the case of one particular field extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$, and let $\{V_n\}$ be a collection of closed subschemes. We say that this collection is *relatively schematically dense* in $X$ if, for all $k$-schemes $S$, the only closed subscheme of $X_S$ containing all $V_{n, S}$ is $X$ itself.

I believe that it is equivalent to require that the collection $V_{n, k'}$ is scheme-theoretically dense in $X_{k'}$ for some arbitrary field extension $k'/k$, in the sense that the only closed subscheme of $X_{k'}$ containing all of these closed subschemes is $X_{k'}$, and I would like to verify my proof. Clearly this condition is necessary.

For sufficiency, we first reduce to the case $k = k'$. Otherwise, suppose there exists some $k$-scheme $S$ and some closed subscheme $V \subseteq X_S$ containing each $V_{n, S}$. Then $V_{k'}$ contains each $V_{n, S_{k'}}$ as a subscheme of $X_{k'}$. Moreover, if $V \subsetneq X$, then its sheaf of ideals $\mathscr{I}_V$ is a nonzero subsheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$. The sheaf of ideals of $V_{k'}$ in $X_{k'}$ is $\mathscr{I} \otimes_k k'$, which is nonzero if $\mathscr{I} \neq 0$ by flatness of the field extension $k'/k$, so we conclude that $V \subsetneq X$. Hence relative schematic density holds if it holds after base change to $k'$.

Now suppose that the collection $V_{n}$ is scheme-theoretically dense in $X$. It is equivalent to say that $\bigcap_{n} \mathscr{I}_{n} = 0$, where $\mathscr{I}_n$ is the ideal sheaf of $V_n$ and the intersection is taken as subsheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$. If $S$ is any $k$-scheme, then the collection $V_{n, S}$ is scheme-theoretically dense in $X$ if and only if they are scheme-theoretically dense on each open affine chart, so it suffices to prove the claim in the case that $X = \mathrm{Spec} \, A$ and $S = \mathrm{Spec} \, B$ are affine, where $A$ and $B$ are $k$-algebras. If $I_n$ is a collection of ideals in $A$ satisfying $\bigcap_n I_n = 0$, then it is also true that $\bigcap_n I_n \otimes_k B = 0$ inside $A \otimes_k C$, since an element in this intersection must be some linear combination of elements of the form $a \otimes b$ with $a \in I_n$ for all $I_n$. We conclude that $\bigcap_{n} \mathscr{I}_{n} = 0$ implies $\bigcap_n \mathscr{I}_{V_{n, S}} = 0$, which is equivalent to saying that the $V_{n, S}$ are scheme-theoretically dense in $X_S$, as desired.

Am I making any subtle mistakes? If I am completely wrong about my claim, a counterexample would be helpful. I originally wanted to prove this lemma to show that the collection $A[\ell^n]$ is relatively schematically dense in $A$, where $A$ is an abelian variety and $\ell \neq \mathrm{char}(k)$, by reducing to the case of the algebraic closure.